# web crawler can't get the dynamic generate url

Tags: javascript, python, web-crawler

Im writing a toy program to crawl some pics from a website.But the url generate with js . anyone can tell me how to deal with it..
the parsed url:

and the original webpage :
http://jandan.net/ooxx/page-323#comments

anyway,thanks

Comment: The parsed url like this: <img onload="jandan_load_img(this)" src="//img.jandan.net/img/blank.gif"/>

Comment: how about @colt？

Comment: 兄弟@colt是啥，能不能说清楚点啊 。@Joiningss

Answer (score 0):

The image src URI is encoded and encrypted, you need to decrypt the 'img-hash' by b64, md5 and site's own method.

Follow the function 'jandon_load_img' and capture it's return value 'c'.

You can also learn `selenium` with WebDriver to extract the HTML page after javascript run.

Comment: Actually，I know how to deal this with selenium . but I just want to deal with it without the browser.